# How to supply a PostgreSQL notice handling function in OCaml Caqti?

Tags: postgresql, ocaml, caqti

Caqti exhibits the default behavior for handling PostgreSQL notices (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-notice-processing.html).

That is, all PostgreSQL notices are **printed to stderr** when using Caqti, which is annoying.

- Is it possible to tell Caqti to provide a difference notice processing function to PostgreSQL?
- Alternatively, is it possible to suppress all notices, warnings etc. of PostgreSQL in Caqti?

Comment: Since I received no responses on SO, I'm trying to ask this question on the Caqti issue tracker: https://github.com/paurkedal/ocaml-caqti/issues/33